# Copying and Renaming Android Project in Eclipse without error

Tags: android, eclipse

For some reason, I need to create multiple copies of Android application with different package and application name.

Here's what I did:

1. Copy and paste the project in eclipse
2. RIGHT CLICK project name> Android tools> Rename Application Package
3. src> package name> refactor > rename> Checked update references and rename subpackages

But after doing this, import errors appear that leads to other errors.
I believe because of this errors, R.java wont appear as well.
I am working on a big project so fixing imports manually is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many things, 
in turns out that my project has only one main error.
After resolving that error and cleaning the project, the imports are fixed.